# Modify and compile Android Status Bar project (SystemUI.apk)

Tags: android, statusbar

I have an ".apk" file, In this, I want to change the behaviour of the status bar. I'm able to modify its files in "res" folder but I want to write new code, so I've downloaded what I understand is the project [link](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/tree/ics-plus-aosp/packages/SystemUI)

My question is: How can I compile it? it seems to be a part of a much more generic project, I've read people in internet saying it's possible but I'm not able to import lots of referenced classes (com.android.internal.R for example).

I'm sorry if it's a newbie question or if it's not clear enough, but if someone who has done this before could help I'll be grateful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have to get [the whole project](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/tree/ics-plus-aosp) and not only the SystemUI subdirectory.

Answer (score 0):

Try to refresh the project. The R file has to be generated and make sure that you import the right API's to compile your project

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I've tried it but it still not working

Comment: @Oritm: that R's package is not the application's R but an external library R file.